# Why PyCharm does not recognize user environment variables configuration?

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, keyerror, python-3.9

I tried to use the PyCharm user environment variable configuration, however, it throws KeyError. If I try to set the variables via commands it works, but via configuration it does not.
I will appreciate any help.

```
import os

print(os.environ['BLA']) 



(venv) (base) mikam@Mikas-MacBook-Pro Scripts % python implementVar.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikam/Desktop/Scripts/implementVar.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(os.environ['BLA'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'BLA'
```

Comment: Personally, I've gone with using `.env` file and building my APIs to import it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK,
apparently for **terminal** and **run**,
there are different places where you define configurations.

During the whole time,
I used the configurations at the top right corner,
While there is another place in the **terminal settings**
where it is also possible to configure the Terminal environment variables only.

Anyhow it solved the problem--> also necessary to restart Pycharm after adding each parameter.
Hope it will help someone :)

Comment: for `zsh` users, PyCharm will source `.zshenv` file. Make sure you restart!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your use of `venv` is intercepting these env variables.  If you are on Windows, there is a separate feature in `venv` to set environment variables for the virtual Python environment.  https://www.roelpeters.be/set-environment-variables-in-virtual-environment-python/

Alternatively, you could allow PyCharm to manage the Python interpreter outside of venv.  PyCharm has a multiple interpreter management subsystem of its own.  Combining them is probably somehow causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me this solved it:

In the menu go to:

`File` > `Settings` > `Build` > `Execution` > `Deployment` > `Console`> `Python` > `Console`

Environmental Variables. --> Add your variables here